# I have wood block of 50 * 50 * 50 mm. I want to make 1mm hole ( depth), having diameter of 40mm. Which power tool should I use?

Tags: wood, carpentry

My question is about making a big hole in wood.

I have wood block of 50 * 50 * 50 mm. I want to make 1 millimeter hole ( depth), having diameter of 40 millimeter. Which power tool should I use?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.  Drill Press.

Answer (score 1):

The best bet for this is to use a drill press so that you can maintain positioning of the block and the drilling tool for an even and square operation. A drill press often also includes a depth stop to help with maintaining a repeatable drill depth if you are producing multiple parts.

[image]

The type of drilling bit you want to use for an operation like this would be a Forstner bit. For shallow depth drilling you will want to use the type of bit that looks as follows with the smooth sharp radial cutters.

[image]

Avoid the type of bit that has the multi toothed radial cutters as this will not give you as smooth of edge on your shallow depression.

[image]

For safety sake make sure to securely clamp the small block of wood to the table of the drill press. One recommendation to make things a lot safer is to drill your shallow depressions into the face of a longer piece of material and then cut it down to size. It is far easier to clamp a larger piece.